# Verify prometheus metric was updated

Tags: prometheus

I wanted to do something like:

```
time() - timestamp(my_metric)
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to know how much time passed since latest metric update ?

Comment: time() - timestamp(node_cpu_num) worked pretty well to me (Prometheus 2.26.0). What is your issue?

Comment: The value of ```time() - timestamp(my_metric)``` for me loops despite ```timestamp(my_metric)``` being constant.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira did you do something similar in the past ? Looking to see if a metric was updated ?

Comment: timestamp(metric) is not constant, it's like time() by moving in "steps".

Comment: and timestamp(my_metric) is constant for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timestamp()` shows you the timestamp of the last scrape. Every time the metric gets scraped it receives a new timestamp, regardless of whether its value changed or not. Therefore, `time() - timestamp(some_metric)` usually equals to the scrape interval you've set for the job.

If you want to know when the value has changed, you have two options:

1. Create a timestamp (gauge) metric. Each time you change the value of the metric that you want to track, set the value of the timestamp metric to current unixtime. Then you can learn how much time have passed since the last update with a query like this:

   ```
   time() - my_timestamp_metric
   ```
2. Use `changes()` function. It will not tell you ***when*** a change has happened but ***if*** there was a change during the given interval:

   ```
   changes(my_metric[5m])
   ```

   '0' means no changes; any other number, obviously, there were changes.

Comment: Useful answer regarding the timestamp() being last scraped time ! But what I need to know is when was it last updated, not the value changed :).

Answer (score 1):

It worked pretty well to me on Prometheus 2.26.2.

For example, this is the time() metric:

[image: time()]

And this is the timestamp(prometheus_build_info) metric:

[image: timestamp(prometheus_build_info]

Finally this is the time()-timestamp(prometheus_build_info) metric:

[image: time()-timestamp(prometheus_build_info)]

Comment: As you can see, its periodic between 0 and 60 the difference overtime, why is that ? For me its periodic between 0 and 14

Comment: It should be same shape as timestamp(prometheus_build_info) but it aint ...  why the f not ?

Comment: "time" is a continuous line and "timestamp" is like "time" but updated every time the metric is scraped (1 min = 60 in my case). The "time - timestamp" changes from 0 (when "timestamp" was just scraped) and 60 (when "timestamp" is near to be scraped again). Take a look at the images to better understand.

Comment: Oh I understand thanks !